# Android Studio 2.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm starting in android development via Android Studio 2.3.1

As soon as I installed the program and its requirements, they started my problems.

I've tried a lot for help and I did not succeed.

I created a new project and when I started the program, I got the message:

"USAGE:
Unable to start daemon process.
This problem might be caused by an incorrect configuration of the daemon.
...
Following arguments are required:

But, the best comes now ...
By the existing terminal in the android studio itself there is no mistake !!!

Paths to sources
gradle version 3.3

Please... Help me

[Tree Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3fOr.png)

[Terminal Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUIWq.png)

[Terminal Windows][3]

[PC configuration][4]

[ambient variables][5]

Answer (score 0):

Open the gradle.properties file, and add this line at the end `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m`, then do Build->Clean Project or just close it and reopen it and it should work.